# How can I rollover an index having many writing aliases on ElasticSearch/OpenSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have the following scenario, an index that must be rotate periodically (based on max primary shards size), and many write aliases pointing to it. For example:

```
read_alias_1  ---> idx_A_0002 <--- write_alias_1
read_alias_2  ---> idx_A_0002 <--- write_alias_2

read_alias_1  ---> idx_A_0001
read_alias_2  ---> idx_A_0001

read_alias_3  ---> idx_B_0002 <--- write_alias_3

read_alias_3  ---> idx_B_0001
```

The purpose of this strategy is all about space management and security. Because some "writers" write more than others, we are trying to avoid having them writing on the same index, otherwise they will cause the creation of too many shards (e.g.: write_alias_3). On the other hand, for some "writers" it's ok to store their data on the same indexes (e.g.: write_alias_1 and write_alias_2).

The issue I'm struggling is about how to rotate the indexes automatically and make all the "writers" aliases to stop pointing to the old index and start pointing to the new index. I have tried a couple of things but none seems to work.

The close I could get to develop a solution to these was using the ISM and rollover policy [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/ism/policies/#example-policy-with-ism-templates-for-the-alias-action). However it doesn't work as I expected because the property `plugins.index_state_management.rollover_alias` doesn't accept an array of aliases to rollover.
Any ideas?